# Function called when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a Wordpress option which is a checkbox, with id="is_custom_colour".

When this check box is checked, I want a hidden option to show.

I have code which works when the checkbox is clicked, but this fails if the option "is_custom_colour" is already checked.  You have to click it (uncheck it), to show the hidden options.

This is the original code which works fine but is not functionally ideal (custom_colour is the id of the hidden option):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#is_custom_colour').click(function() {
        $('#section-custom_colour').fadeToggle(400);
    });

    if ($('#is_custom_colour:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        $('#section-custom_colour_hidden').show();
    }

});
</script>
```

If I change this to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($('#is_custom_colour:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        $('#section-custom_colour').fadeToggle(400);
    });

    if ($('#is_custom_colour:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        $('#section-custom_colour_hidden').show();
    }

});
</script>
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using, `.is(':checked')` to check whether the checkbox is checked

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   if($('#is_custom_colour').is(':checked')){
      $('#section-custom_colour_hidden').show();
    }
});


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="is_custom_colour" value="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      Checkbox</label>   
</form>
<div id="section-custom_colour_hidden" style="display:none">HIDDEN AREA</div>
```

Comment: I now have a problem.  is_custom_colour is set to true.  Therefore, the hidden custom_colour option should now show.  But when I reload the Wordpress theme options page, it doesn't show.  I have to click the is_custom_colour checkbox (**which unselects it**) to show the custom_colour option.  This is the reverse intention.  The check to see if the checkbox is checked is not happening when the page first loads.

Comment: I do not understand what you are mentioning

Comment: The code you are helping me with is part of a Wordpress theme options screen.  When the theme options screen first loads, it is not "show"ing #section-custom_colour_hidden.  To show #section-custom_colour_hidden I have to click the check box #is_custom_colour, which unticks it.  It should need to be ticked for #section-custom_colour_hidden to be displayed, not unticked.

Comment: you might have not hided the "section-custom_colour_hidden" element in loading first

Comment: check whether wordpress sets it hide on the load?